# blob.Properties.ContentType when written to Blob Container is always application/octet stream

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

I am simply writing a json file to a Blob (please see my code below). I need it to be content = application/json but instead the blob json file reads "application/octet-stream" every time. I have set the blob.properties ContentType to = "application/json" but when I look in the Storage Explorer it says "application/octet-stream" every time.

```
static public void WriteBlob(string filename, string data)
        {
            string storageConnectionString = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=scadametrics;AccountKey=xxxxxxxxxxnfrsFRd/49Dmhn0HwKbxmpiA==;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net";
            var storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(storageConnectionString);
            var client = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
            var container = client.GetContainerReference("azfunc-out");
//            string fileName = companyId.ToString() + "\\" + Guid.NewGuid();
            var blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(filename);
            blob.Properties.ContentType = "application/json";

            using (CloudBlobStream x = blob.OpenWriteAsync().Result)
            {
                byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);
                x.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                x.Flush();
                x.Close();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should call `blob.SetPropertiesAsync` to really save the content type to server.